# SQL - sales values are multiplied because of duplicate values in join table, how to get around it

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I’m just learning sql (I’m using postgresql) and I would like to ask if somebody could help me with my query.

I’m trying to get some data from sales table and match it with data from customer account table and branch table.

Below is my query and it works fine. But I’ve noticed that some sales values are multiplied because in table where account name is (customer account) are for one account 2 rows of data . 
In customer account table is column with modification date. So, I’m sure I could select only the most recent row. But I don’t know how to add it into my query. Please could somebody help?

```
select s.accountid, 
       ca.accountname, 
       s.branchnumber, 
       b.branchname, 
       sum(s.revenue) as revenue, 
       sum(s.revenue)-sum(s.cost) as gp
from sales s 
  left join customeraccount ca on s.accountid = ca.accountid and s.company = ca.company
  left join branches b on s.branchnumber = b.branchnumber and s.company = b.company
where s.company = 'FR1'
and s.salestype = 1
and s.deliverydate between '2018-01-01' and '2018-06-30'
group by s.accountid, ca.accountname, s.branchnumber, b.branchname
```

`

Comment: so customer account has two rows with the same accountid and accountname and company but different modified date?

Comment: Account and country is always the same. Account name could  be different if account was renamed. So row with the most recent modification date has correct data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

This query will give you unique combination of `accountid` + `accountname` + `company` that is the last modified row for the every `accountid` + `company`

```
SELECT customeraccount.accountid, customeraccount.accountname, customeraccount.company
FROM customeraccount 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT accountid, company, max(modified_on) AS last_modified_on
 FROM customeraccount 
 group by accountid, company) AS customeraccount_last_modified
ON  customeraccount.accountid = customeraccount_last_modified.accountid
AND customeraccount.company = customeraccount_last_modified.company
AND customeraccount.modified_on = customeraccount_last_modified.last_modified_on
```

Exaplanation:

1. We want to estalish the last modified date (I called it `modified_on`) for every `accountid` + `company` :

   ```
   SELECT accountid, company, max(modified_on) AS last_modified_on
   FROM customeraccount 
   group by accountid, company
   ```
2. Now we want to fetch `accountname` from the row that has `modified_on` value as the last modified we fetched before. So I created a join between `customeraccount` and the  query from pt.1 (it serves as temp temp table for this query only) based on equality of the three columns from the query. and then you can fetch from `customeraccount` whatever column you wish and be certain that you get uniqe values for every `accountid` + `company` (hope it is clear...)

You can take this query and put it in your query in the `FROM` clause,  make sure you create an alias for it.

Answer (score 0):

as Sharon Ben Asher pointed out which i overlooked you need the last row modified. I updated my answer to reflect this.  I am using two CTEs. One , called "lastdate", for accountid/company and the last modified date and the other called "customer, for holding the customeraccount row where it equals the last modified date. In the from clause you just replace the customeraccount with the customer CTE.

```
with lastdate as (
Select accountid, 
       company, 
       max(modified_date) modified_date
from customeraccount
group by accountid, 
         company )
,cutomers as ( 
Select accountid, 
       company, 
       accountname
from customeraccount 
inner join  lastdate on  (lastdate.accountid = customeraccount.accountid and 
            lastdate.company = customeraccount.company and 
            lastdate.modified_date = customeraccount.modified_date ))
select s.accountid, 
       ca.accountname, 
       s.branchnumber, 
       b.branchname, 
       sum(s.revenue) as revenue, 
       sum(s.revenue)-sum(s.cost) as gp
from sales s 
  left join cutomers ca on s.accountid = ca.accountid and s.company = ca.company
  left join branches b on s.branchnumber = b.branchnumber and s.company = b.company
where s.company = 'FR1'
and s.salestype = 1
and s.deliverydate between '2018-01-01' and '2018-06-30'
group by s.accountid, ca.accountname, s.branchnumber, b.branchname
```

-HTH

Comment: OP stated she wants to get values from last modified row

Comment: @SharonBenAsher thank you for pointing that out. I updated my answer.